# Excel code crashes after a couple of uses, opening a connection to Access

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access, office-2016

We have an Excel 2016 quoting tool that uses VBA code to compare the product codes entered against an Access database and then update another sheet with the details needed for our CRM system.
This is an interim solution until a more permanent one becomes available.

We can capture 5 quotes, generate the CRM sheet. On the 6th quote when you generate the CRM sheet the following VBA Error shows up.

> System Error &H8000FFF (-2147418113)

Fixes I tried, increase the buffer size, clear clipboard. Removing the buffer causes the error almost immediately.

I found in debugging that the crash will happen at `cn.Open` as it tries to open a connection to Access.

```vb
Function CRM_Update(PROD As String)
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    If PROD = "" Then
        emptyline = emptyline + 1
        Exit Function
    Else
        emptyline = 0
    End If
    Set cn = New ADODB.Connection
    cn.ConnectionString = "DSN=MS Access Database;DBQ=C:\database\CRMSA.accdb;DriverId=25;FIL=MS Access;MaxBufferSize=4096;PageTimeout=5;"
    cn.Open
    Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset**
    rs.Open "select * from ARTGROUP WHERE  ART = '" & PROD & "';", cn, adOpenStatic
    If rs.RecordCount = 0 Then
        MsgBox (PROD & "  " & " not found in article group")
        Exit Function
    End If
```

This looks to be related to memory use because you can get further into the generate process if you have very little open but as soon as you have a lot of items open: Chrome, Outlook and other applications you can get maybe 5 generate attempts.
On a virtual machine with only 4GB of RAM I was able to do this process over 40 times without a single crash.
On my work laptop with 16GB of RAM and only this open I was able to generate about 16 times before that error comes up.

Event log:

> The system has called a custom component and that component has failed
> and generated an exception. This indicates a problem with the custom
> component. Notify the developer of this component that a failure has
> occurred and provide them with the information below. Component Prog
> ID: SC.Pool 455 1 Method Name: IDispenserDriver::CreateResource
> Process Name: EXCEL.EXE Exception: c0000005 Address: 0X58101018

I removed all custom add-ins and still get this crash. I only have the following MS references in the sheet running namely:

VB for Applications
MS Excel 16.0 Object Library
OLE Automation
MS Office 16.0 Object Library
MS Access 16.0 Object Library
Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 2.8 Library

I tried rebuilding the database, compact and repair and decompile but it has no effect.
I have white listed the database in AV program with no change.

*edit*

Module 1 is the first VB script that I think opens the Access database.
Module 2 is VB script that says Cell A in Worksheet A goes to Cell A in Worksheet B, it too is also opening a connection to the Access database but I have not included the formula for the moving part.
There is a third module that compares the data from the Excel sheet with the Access database and then assigns product codes.

Module 1:

```vb
Public Function CRM_shortDescr(PROD As String)
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set cn = New ADODB.Connection
    cn.ConnectionString = "DSN=MS Access Database;DBQ=C:\database\CRMSA.accdb;DriverId=25;FIL=MS Access;MaxBufferSize=4096;PageTimeout=5;"
    '   The database name was set incorrectly here. Changed to correct name.
    cn.Open
    Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
    rs.Open "select * from ARTGROUP WHERE  ART = '" & PROD & "';", cn, adOpenStatic
    If rs.RecordCount = 0 Then
        MsgBox (PROD & "  " & " not found in article group")
        Exit Function
    End If
    PRGR = rs!crm
    rs.Close
    rs.Open "select * from PRGR WHERE  PRGR = '" & Left(PRGR, 2) & "';", cn, adOpenStatic
    If rs.RecordCount = 0 Then
        MsgBox (PRGR & "  " & " not found in article group")
        Exit Function
    End If
    CRM_shortDescr = rs!Descr
    rs.Close
End Function
```

Module 2 is the one above at the start of this post, missing lines are:

```vb
italyrow = 19 + emptyline
    linenumber = ActiveCell.Row
    linenumbercrm = linenumber - italyrow
<Formual starts to move from Sheet A to Sheet B but looks like the following
`Worksheets("CRM").Cells(linenumbercrm, 1).Value = Worksheets("Local Quotation").Range("COUNTRY")>
rs.Close
End Function
```

Comment: Before you `SET cn`, you should `Dim cn as ADODB.Connection`. Also, try to uncheck `Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 2.8 Library` and add it again after

Comment: What will Dim CN do? 

I recreated the crash, uncheck MS ActiveX, tried to generate and had the crash, checked MS ActiveX and clicked on generate and the crash still happened.

Comment: ADO 2.8 is very much outdated. Use the most actual version, likely ADO 6.1 (unless you're running a very old version of Windows as well).

Comment: Updating ADO to 6.1 makes no difference :).

Comment: You are not closing any objects, so you may run out of ressources.

Comment: @Gustav So there is a bunch of code after what I posted, they just say what cell goes to which other cell but at the end of the code there is a rs.Close line. So I imagine that is closing the connection? Or is there something else that needs to be closed?

Comment: Yes. The connection will have to be closed as well. Or: Open the connection, run your repeated opening/closing of recordsets, and finally close the connection.

Comment: @Gustav They should auto-close after they go out of scope, though, so it should not be a problem. But I remember something about that not working properly in old ADO versions

Comment: @ErikA: True, but "something" is eating up memory, so you must look in all corners for that something that shouldn't be there.

Comment: Wow. This is now going far and above my understanding but onward and upward is the way to learn :). I take it the rs.Close is not closing the connection to the database so after some Googling I found the following: cn.Close to close the connection and I added it after each function where there is cn.Open, this seemed to have worked as I was able to generate an extra 2 attempts but on the ninth attempt that same error came back.

Comment: @Anakha56 sorry didn't read comment to the end. But as it improved after cn.close, there may be other connections not properly closed and you still use old version 2.8 instead of 6.

Comment: ODBC Driver is up-to-date? Do you hide (module/global) declarattions for Adodb.Connection/Recodset or do you miss`Option Explicit`?

Comment: I went into the VB side, deselected the 2.8 reference and selected the 6 reference and no change was observed. Is there something else I must do to change to 6? RE ODBC driver, this is on Windows 10 so I assume the driver is being kept up to date by Windows Update. I don't understand the Option Explicit part. Something I need to mention, I did not write this code I am trying to troubleshoot the problem.

Comment: ODBC Driver is installed with windows, but not updated. Check version. Read about [Option Explicit](https://riptutorial.com/vba/example/2956/implicit-and-explicit-declaration). You tried`Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0`provider?

Comment: In Module 1: `If rs.RecordCount = 0 Then … Exit Function` then neither the `Connection (cn)` nor the `RecordSet (rs)` are closed. Include `rs.Close` and `Cn.Close` before `Exit Function` or use a GOSUb to an "Exception Handler".

Comment: @EEM I should have mentioned that the code I posted is the original code. I added those close commands and it worked nicely in that while watching the script run I can see it open and close the Access database. But the error still comes up and it makes no attempt to open said database from the first click to error. ComputerVersteher I did try adding this "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\database\CRMSA.accdb" but no change. Ref are

 VB for Applications
Excel 16.0 Object Library
OLE Automation
Office 16.0 Object Library
Access 16.0 Object Library
ActiveX Data Obj 6.1

Comment: Problem appears to be solved and it had nothing to do with the code <_<. KB4484218 is the culprit that is breaking everything somehow.

Comment: Please post this as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Problem appears to be solved and it had nothing to do with the code <_<. [KB4484218](https://support.microsoft.com/en-za/help/4484218/january-7-2020-update-for-office-2016-kb4484218) is the culprit that is breaking everything somehow.